# Centering a rotated image using Reportlab

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to center a rotated image on Reportlab, but I'm having issues using the correct calculation for the placement.

Here's the current code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from PIL import Image as PILImage

import requests
import math


def main(rotation):
    # create a new PDF with Reportlab
    a4 = (595.275590551181, 841.8897637795275)
    c = canvas.Canvas('output.pdf', pagesize=a4)
    c.saveState()

    # loading the image:
    img = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5Rj.png', stream=True)

    img = PILImage.open(img.raw)
    width, height = img.size

    # We calculate the bouding box of a rotated rectangle
    angle_radians = rotation * (math.pi / 180)
    bounding_height = abs(width * math.sin(angle_radians)) + abs(height * math.cos(angle_radians))
    bounding_width = abs(width * math.cos(angle_radians)) + abs(height * math.sin(angle_radians))

    a4_pixels = [x * (100 / 75) for x in a4]

    offset_x = (a4_pixels[0] / 2) - (bounding_width / 2)
    offset_y = (a4_pixels[1] / 2) - (bounding_height / 2)
    c.translate(offset_x, offset_y)

    c.rotate(rotation)
    c.drawImage(ImageReader(img), 0, 0, width, height, 'auto')

    c.restoreState()
    c.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(45)
```

So far, here's what I did:

1. Calculating the boundaries of a rotated rectangle (since it will be bigger)
2. Using these to calculate the position of the center of the image (size / 2 - image / 2) for width and height.

Two issues appear that I can't explain:

1. The "a4" variable is in points, everything else is in pixels. If I change them to pixels for calculating the position (which is logical, using `a4_pixels = [x * (100 / 75) for x in a4]`). The placement is incorrect for a rotation of 0 degree. If I keep the a4 in points, it works ... ?
2. If I change the rotation, it breaks even more.

So my final question: How can I calculate the `offset_x` and `offset_y` values to ensure it's always centered regardless of the rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you translate the canvas, you are literally moving the origin (0,0) point and all draw operations will be relative to that.

So in the code below, I moved the origin to the middle of the page.
Then I rotated the "page" and drew the image on the "page". No need to rotate the image since its canvas axes have rotated.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import requests

def main(rotation):
    c = canvas.Canvas('output.pdf', pagesize=A4)
    c.saveState()

    # loading the image:
    img = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5Rj.png', stream=True)
    img = PILImage.open(img.raw)
    # The image dimensions in cm
    width, height = img.size

    # now move the canvas origin to the middle of the page
    c.translate(A4[0] / 2, A4[1] / 2)
    # and rotate it
    c.rotate(rotation)
    # now draw the image relative to the origin
    c.drawImage(ImageReader(img), -width/2, -height/2, width, height, 'auto')

    c.restoreState()
    c.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(45)
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect. But now I'm having the same issue if I want to place the image on top, centered, and rotated by 45 degrees. This doesn't work anymore (of course I've updated the `c.translate(A4[0]/2, A4[1]-img_height)` and drawImage with width=img_width/2, height=0). It works well without rotation, but fails as soon as I add 45degrees. Any idea?

Comment: Remember, the translate and rotate actions are affecting the canvas and not the drawing. Hope that helps?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in my response. When it affects the canvas, does it means the full A4 (in this case), with a rotating at the center of that A4? Or something else? I'm confused with when I position it in the top... :/

Comment: Tricky to explain. When you're drawing, you're drawing on the cartesian plane. Moving the canvas just states where your drawing plane is on the page. Imagine you were drawing with a pen, rather than constantly shifting your elbow to get a new angle, you shift the page instead and keep your arm straight.